# Problems with " when sending emails [sendmail + PHP + Symfony]

Tags: php, html, symfony, email, sendmail

I've developped an almost perfect API with **PHP and Symfony 2** that sends e-mails with the help of my mail server : **sendmail**. My problem is that I can send emails with simple text and simple HTML but when I have something like : `<h1 style="color:red;">HI</h1>`
 in the body I don't receive the mail. **I've resolved that problem putting backslashes when I have the symbol *"* .** But this make me another problem and the html code received is horrible. I've searched on internet but I can't find someone who has the same problem.
There's my code :

```
    public function api_send_email($from,$to,$token,$subject,$content, $from_email_id, $to_email_id)
{
    $list_unsubscribe = $this->container->get('router')->generate('api_mod_com_unsubscribeOne', array(
        'fsUserId' => $from_email_id,
        'toEmail' => $to_email_id
    ));

    $from = $from." <info@fidelsys.eu>";
    $headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
    $headers .= "To: ".$to."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers .= "List-unsubscribe: ".$list_unsubscribe."\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . PHP_VERSION;
    $headers .= "\r\n";
    $headers .= $content."\r\n";

    // debugg
    mail("dev2.fidelsys@mail.ru","tests", $headers );

    $cmd = 'echo "'.$headers.'" | sendmail -t -N \'success,failure\' -V '.$token;
    shell_exec ( $cmd );
```

I've resolved the problem putting :

```
$content = addslashes($content);
```

But I receive emails with broken links and where the code seems like this :

```
<td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" style=\"color:#606060;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:150%;padding-top:10px;padding-right:40px;padding-bottom:40px;padding-left:40px;text-align:left\">
```

What is normal with the addslashes function. 
**PS: I don't have any error in the server or symfony logs.If I delete the addslashes function my mail desapears.**

Comment: Use a library for sending emails. There are a lot of issues you're not caring of. Try phpmailer for example.

Comment: symfony has built-in supoprt of swiftmailer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html

Comment: Thank you ! I just had to finish what was developped before and I'have only this little bug...